# Window not showing up on Mac JAVA

Tags: java, javafx

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;

public class Main extends Application {
    Button button;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        stage.setTitle("GAME");
        button = new Button();
        button.setText("CLICK HERE");

        StackPane layout = new StackPane();
        layout.getChildren().add(button);

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout, 300, 250);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Trying to run but the window won't show up, any thoughts on how to fix. I've gone through other posts but no luck. By the way, I'm using IntelliJ. Just started learning JavaFX.

Comment: I just ran this on my mac from the command line and the window appeared.  I do not use an IDE; I compile and run from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

This is in my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH_TO_FX=/usr/local/bin/javafx-sdk-14/lib
alias javafxc="javac --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing"
alias javafx="java --module-path ${PATH_TO_FX} --add-modules=javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.media,javafx.web,javafx.swing"
```

To compile:

```
javafxc Main.java
```

To run:

```
javafx Main
```

Comment: I know the compiling part but how do I do the .bash_profile part?

Comment: You can edit this file in terminal.   If it's not there, create it.

Comment: Used eclipse, added arguments, and disabled an argument. Now it works.